# Cell fracture pieces held back

Tags: rigidbody

I'm in Blender 3.5. In my scene, a car crashes through a door. First I put a Cell Fracture on the meshes that make up the door, then I applied a Force Field (Bold) to project the pieces of the meshes created by the Cell Fracture.

However, when the door explodes, instead of the pieces propelling away, it's as if they're held back by an invisible wall.

[image]

How can I fix this?